# Spinnaker configuration

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I'm having question about spinnaker-Halyard installation, Can spinnaker manage AWS cloud provider without being installed on EC2 instance?. meaning that can I install spinnaker locally and add aws account and manage pipelines

Answer (score 4):

> Can spinnaker manage AWS cloud provider without being installed on EC2 instance?

Spinnaker can be installed on any Ubuntu server - for example, you could run a Spinnaker instance from [Google's Click to Deploy image](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/click-to-deploy-images/spinnaker) and have it manage your EC2 account.

Spinnaker is comprised of a bunch of microservices, so running it on a local workstation may be cumbersome. I suggest dedicating a specific machine to it. Alternatively, if you're set on running it locally, you could install Halyard locally and point it to a Minikube installation on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the these many providers under your spinnaker setup 
https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/

- App Engine
- Amazon Web Services
- Azure
- Cloud Foundry
- DC/OS Google
- Compute Engine
- Kubernetes (legacy)
- Kubernetes V2 (manifest based)
- Openstack Oracle

You just need to integrate your service accounts into spinnaker to authorize resource creation.

Comment: i just wished it was that easy. It presents all sorts of trouble when locally installed in a debian installation such as ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Yes It will work just you need to create service account and Need to pass kubeconfig file to spinnaker, then spinnaker handle Deployment part automatically, you need to configure spinnaker for that.

Some useful link
https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/security/authorization/service-accounts/
https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/